# php server has no reponse after ios send data

Tags: php, ios

I just want to send device token to php server and store that in MySQL. But no matter I tried, the php server has no response, I used `var_dump($_POST), var_dump($_GET), var_dump($_REQUEST), var_dump($_FILES);`, it just is empty.

The ios code is here:

```
// send to server
let url = URL(string: "http://www.ios.jobyme88.com/KidsLearnHindi/connect-to-server.php?token=\(data.deviceToken)")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  if let error = error {
    print ("error: \(error)")
    return
  }
  guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
    return
  }
  print(response)
  print("send")
  
  if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
    mimeType == "application/json",
    let data = data,
    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print ("got data: \(dataString)")
  }
}
task.resume()
```

The server code is just here:

```
<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>
```

I used to have a working code but I lost it, this problem has took me two days. So weired. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: is there any error when you call api from iOS Side??

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a variable as a string constant use string concatenation .

"Url.....php?token=" .  YourStringVariable . "Whatever"    ..

The dot is STRING concatenation but only outside quotes.

And remember anything passed in the URL must be urlEncode( varString ) if it can has non alphanumerical english characters like punctuation , chinese , etc.

Answer (score 0):

This iOS code is working. Changes are 1) I print the data 2) because I was refreshing webpage which is a new request, not iOS request.

```
// send to server
let url = URL(string: "http://www.ios.jobyme88.com/KidsLearnHindi/connect-to-server.php?token=\(data.deviceToken)")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // check error
    if let error = error {
        print ("error: \(error)")
        return
    }
                
    // check response
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
    (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
        print ("server error")
            return
    }
                
    // print data from server
    guard let data = data else {
        print("no data")
        return
    }

    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print ("got data: \(dataString)")
    }

task.resume()
```

server.php

```
echo $_GET['token'];
echo "goood";
```

For POST, I am still looking for a test tool to monitor server data input flow.